# Fix use of overloaded operator '+' is ambiguous?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, methods, operator-overloading

I wrote the following code using C++11 standard:

**.h file:**

```
#include "Auxiliaries.h"

    class IntMatrix {

    private:
        Dimensions dimensions;
        int *data;

    public:
        int size() const;

        IntMatrix& operator+=(int num);
    };
```

---

Bit I am getting and error saying that:

> error: use of overloaded operator '+' is ambiguous (with operand types
>   'const mtm::IntMatrix' and 'int')
>       return matrix+scalar;

Any idea of what causes this behaviour and how may I fix it?

Comment: Those definitions should be in the `mtm` namespace otherwise you're declaring different functions, hence the ambiguity.

Comment: @smith -- *but why is that?* -- Those are the rules of C++.  Those implementations are outside of the namespace they are declared in.

Comment: @smith the overloaded function is in scope `mtm`, but you're using `using mtm::IntMatrix;` and `using mtm::Dimensions;` only.

Comment: Someone told me before that I can write all definitions inside the .cpp file

Comment: @smith -- You can write it in a separate cpp.  The issue is that you didn't do it correctly.

Comment: There is no declaration or definition for `mtm::Dimensions::getCol()` in your code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: _"Note: the suggested solution gave me linker error:"_ That's wrong. The suggested solution fixed the compile step. Missing function declarations caused errors in the linker step.

Comment: @ThomasSablik right, I will edit that, but why I got downvote, what did I do wrong, I got blocked from asking guys :-(

Comment: You don't provide a [mcve]. The error message was about the function `mtm::Dimensions::getCol()` but your code doesn't contain that function. How could someone  solve that problem? The question is not answerable. That's a bad question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared the operators in the `mtm` namespace so the definitions should be in the `mtm` namespace.

Since you define them outside, you've actually two different functions:

```cpp
namespace mtm {
    IntMatrix operator+(IntMatrix const&, int);
}

IntMatrix operator+(IntMatrix const&, int);
```

When you do `matrix + scalar` in `operator+(int, IntMatrix const&)`, both functions are found:

- The one in the namespace via [Argument-Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).
- The one in the global namespace since you are in the global namespace.

You need to define the `operator`s in the namespace you declared them, `mtm`:

```cpp
// In your .cpp
namespace mtm {

    IntMatrix operator+(IntMatrix const& matrix, int scalar) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: @smith You're probably missing definitions. You should have all three `operator+` and the `operator-` in the `.cpp` file. Plus the two member-functions.

Comment: Also you may have artifacts in your code that made similar mistakes, i.e. using `mtm` namespace in some places, but not in others.

Comment: @smith This is your `.h`. You cannot define the function in your `.h` unless you make them inline, otherwise you're going to define them multiple times.

Comment: But, what if I don't want to write namespace mtm  in my cpp file? can't I use include or using?

Comment: @smith You can add the namespace to the function definition: `IntMatrix mtm::operator+(IntMatrix const& matrix, int scalar) {
        // ...
    }`