# C++ invalid operands to binary expression?

Tags: c++, class, debugging, generics

Why when I Run the following code in main I get:

error: invalid operands to binary expression ('mtm::Matrix' and 'int')

```
mtm::Matrix<int> mat_1(dim_1);
mtm::Matrix<int> mat_2=mat_1+2;//ERROR
```

**Even though I wrote operator+** outside the class like this in .h file:

```
template<class T>
Matrix<T> &Matrix<T>::operator+=(T &t_object) {
    int matrix_size = size();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_size; i++) {
        data[i] += t_object;
    }
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> &matrix, T &t_object) {
    Matrix<T> out = matrix;
    out += t_object;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with operators defined inside or outside the class. Mutable references cannot bind to temporaries in C++. Only `const` references can. Change your template parameters to `const T &`s.

Comment: Are you in the same course https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347462/fix-use-of-overloaded-operator-is-ambiguous?

Comment: yeah @ThomasSablik